# Meaning of ST500 Battery LED indicator

Tags: soundtrap

I'm charging up 2 ST500s for an upcoming deployment. They're both plugged in to a wall charger. Originally the LED light was solid blue, and is now slow blinking for both - but I can't find any indication of what that means in the user manual. Does anyone know how to tell when the internal battery is fully charged, or what the slow blinking blue LED means?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I've used earlier models of SoundTraps (ST300/4300) where the blue indicator means the SoundTrap is charging, and the blue light extinguishes when it is fully charged. See the user manual for those models which describes this in more detail than in the ST500 user manual:http://www.oceaninstruments.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ST-User-Guide.pdf. I can't speak to what the blinking blue means, but you can also check the device's charge with the SoundTrap Host Software:

When you plug the SoundTrap into a computer via USB and open the SoundTrap Host software (downloadable here: https://www.oceaninstruments.co.nz/downloads/), it will tell you on the right side under "Status" the % battery remaining. I know for earlier models & software versions (e.g. ST300) that number given in the software is accurate within 10%; I'm not sure if it's more accurate now but it is good practice to keep charging it for a bit longer after it displays 100% just in case. It will continue charging when you have it plugged into a computer as well (just slower than with a wall outlet).